# jQuery - Best way to select a div based on visibility

Tags: jquery, selector

What is the best way to select a div that is not hidden in a group of hidden div's?

For example:

```
<div id="1" class"group" style="display:none">1</div>
<div id="2" class"group" style="display:none">2</div>
<div id="3" class"group" style="display:block">3</div>
<div id="4" class"group" style="display:none">4</div>
```

How would i select the div that is display:block?

note. This cant be done by ID, as the div are interchangeably hidden and unhidden based on buttons.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$('div.group').css('display') == 'block'
```

or

```
$('div.group').is(':visible')
```

Comment: -1: this won't work, you are selecting child with `.group` within `div`.

Answer (score 3):

See [`:visible`](http://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/) selector. This should do `$("div.group:visible")`.

Also, please check that `class="group"` not `class"group"`

[Live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ZuStH/)

Answer (score 2):

Just use the [visible](http://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/) selector

```
$('div.group:visible')
```

Comment: -1: this won't work, you are selecting child with `.group` within `div`.

Answer (score 1):

You could also use the `:visible` pseudo class:

```
$('div:visible').method();
```

See: http://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/